# Best way to test storyboards with OCMockito

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmockito

I'm trying to test an application based on storyboards. The scenario is a Navigation Controller with a View Controller inside. The test is that performing a segue sets a view controller as destination controller (push segue). I'm using OCMockito and here's my test:

```
MyViewController *mockSut = mock([MyViewController class]);
UINavigationController *nav = mock([UINavigationController class]);

[given(mockSut.navigationController) willReturn:nav];
[mockSut performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:nil];

MKTArgumentCaptor *segueArgument = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
MKTArgumentCaptor *senderArgument = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];

[verify(mockSut) prepareForSegue:[segueArgument capture] sender:[senderArgument capture]];
assertThat([[[segueArgument value] destinationViewController] class], equalTo([MyDestinationViewController class]));
```

But it complains that `prepareForSegue:` method was not invoked.

What's the problem here? Maybe that `performSegueWithIdentifier:` invokes `prepareForSegue:` in an asynchronous way?

Comment: Juan, sut should be real object and not mocked. Writing tests for mocks doesn't bring much value. And because it is mocks it doesn't call real functionality

Comment: I don't know how to verify that prepareforsegue was invoked if the argument to verify isn't a mock object.

Answer (score 2):

Who calls `-prepareForSegue:sender:`? UIKit does. By trying to test that, you're testing UIKit — which is unnecessary. When dealing with a framework (that is, something that calls back to you), the basic pattern is:

- Ensure that you're calling the framework correctly.
- Assume the framework calls back correctly. Pretend that this happened by having your test directly call the method which the framework would call.